# Using Batch file to look through directory for property files and then call command

Tags: batch-file, cmd, conditional-statements

I am trying to drill into the current directory looking for .properties files, and if it is found, run another batch file at this point. I am trying to do something like:

```
@echo off

FOR /D /r %%G in ("*.*") do (
 if there is a file ending with properties
     call other.bat
 )
```

but I have been unable to find a solution and I'd appreciate help.

Comment: Why not use `*.properties`?  It appears you're not taking any alternative action if it's not a properties file.

Comment: I do not understand batch very well I have tried using `(*.properties) do (echo "I've found a properties file")`, which never printed, so I assumed it was not finding the properties file.

Comment: When in doubt, it's always worth running `for /?` and reading through the details of syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your loop is doing a wildcard expansion on directories (`/D`) and recursing (`/r`).

You need to remove the `/D` flag so that wildcard expansion is on file name, but still recurse.  This is probably what you're looking for:

```
for /r %%G in (*.properties) do echo %%G
```

A more complicated way is to recurse through directories and use an inner loop to do file name expansion on each directory.  This frees you up to do other stuff while examining a particular directory:

```
for /D /r %%G in (*.*) do (
    for %%F in (%%G\*.properties) do (
        echo %%F
    )
)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation, it was very clear and also worked beautifully.